# Deleting remote folder in FileZilla

Tags: linux, filezilla

I can't delete a remote folder from my linux shared webserver using FileZilla (Mac/Linux). I've CHMODed a few times to 777 on the folder and its parent as well. I'm using the latest versions of FileZilla. Control/Right-Click -> Delete does nothing. FileZilla refreshes.

EDIT:

It gets worse: FileZilla refuses to enter the directory. It says "permission denied". What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is commonly caused by a hidden file, commonly the `.htaccess` file. If you're using the newer version you can toggle this under **Server -> Force showing hidden files**. You can then go into the directory and see the hidden files (if any) and delete them. If this does not work, contact your host, they will be able to remove the folder for you.

If you have shell access to your webspace, you can use `chown` on the directory. If you do not, contact your host.